# Foreach file in directory jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, directory, foreach

How can I do a foreach(File file in Directory) kind of thing in jQuery.

Thank you!

Comment: And where are the files and directories located you want to foreach over? Client pc or the server?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/371875/local-file-access-with-javascript

Comment: well it could be on the server or another server in the network.

Comment: Yes you can with HTML5: Get all images from local folder: http://stackoverflow.com/a/30839031/408872

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Javascript does not have access to the local file system for obvious security reasons. This is not possible.

Unless you are trying to loop through files on your server, in which case you wouldn't want to use jQuery anyway but something like ASP.NET or PHP or whatever framework you are using.

Comment: from an httprequest perspective, can I find all the let's say stackoverflow.com/home.htm, stackoverflow.com/menu.htm, etc. With a sitemap or something?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('selector').each(function(idx, elm){
    //some code
});
```

Will allow you to iterate over a list, applying the same function to each.  However, accessing the filesystem is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with javascript/jquery to read contents of a directory for security reasons. Imagine you are trying to read the file system of client machine. You can use [FSO (File System Object)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z9ty6h50%28VS.85%29.aspx) but that works only in IE. You can use [server-side languages](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-side_scripting) such as PHP, ASP.Net for accessing the file system.

If you meant a loop with `each`, consider the [`each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) method of though. Example:

```
$('selector').each(function(){
  // your code.....
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If the files are on the client you can't access them for security reasons.

If the files are on the server and you want process the list sever-side you wouldn't use JQuery as it's for client-side scripting.

If the files are on the server and you want to process the list client-side, you could generate the list in the server code and send it down as xml, json, etc.

If the files are on **somebody else's server** your only options is to recursivly follow links on their site, which is not really something you'd want to be doing with Javascript from a client's browser.