# jquery - load all text files and display them

Tags: ajax, jquery

I have been using jQuery pretty long time, but I never learned AJAX, so here I come..

we have this code :

```
$('body').load('hello.txt');
```

Simple enough, now let's say I have multiple text files (I don't know their names) I want to load, 
Can I do that ?
Maybe I need to loop all the text files and load them somehow ?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: How come you "have them" and you don't know their names ? .. Are you able to get list of their names from some web server or something ?

Comment: @Israel is the location of text files known؟

Comment: @BehnamEsmaili yes, the location is the same as the javascript file.

Comment: do you use .net to create the textfiles?

Answer (score 6):

Assuming you have text files in the server in a specific location you can do this:

**HTML markup:**

```
 <div id="fileList">
       here list of files will be loaded so that user can select which one to load
 <div>

 <div id="file-content">
       content of selected file will be loaded here
 <div>
```

**JQuery part :**

```
 $.ajax({
      url : "FileServer/GetFileNames", // this is just a url that is responsible to return files list 
      success : function(data){
          //here a JSON data including filenames expected 
          $.each(data,function(i,item){
                var $fileHolder = $("<div></div>");
                $fileHolder.attr("filename",item.filename).click(function(){
                      $("#file-content").load($(this).attr("filename"));
                }).html(item.filename).appendTo("#fileList");  
          });
      }
 });
```

**JSON Structure expected**

```
   [
      {
          filename : "text1.txt"
      },
      {
          filename : "text2.txt"
      },
      {
          filename : "text3.txt"
      } 
   ]
```

implementing file listing in the server side is up to you.

Comment: Thanks, what should I put in the URL? the folder that includes the text files?

Comment: no.this would be url of an http handler in server. which server technology you are using?

Comment: i don't want to use any backend like asp.net or php or jsp etc... I want to know if it's possible with pure ajax

Answer (score 3):

> Javascript does not have access to the local file system for obvious
>   security reasons. This is not possible.
>
> Unless you are trying to loop through files on your server, in which
>   case you wouldn't want to use jQuery anyway but something like ASP.NET
>   or PHP or whatever framework you are using.

[Foreach file in directory jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3087502/foreach-file-in-directory-jquery)

**UPDATE**

Try this out

```
var files;
$.ajax({
    url: "http://homepage/folder",
    success: function (txt) {
        files = txt.split('<A href="');
    }
});
var fList = new Array();
$(files).each(function () {
    if (this.indexOf('.txt') > -1) {
        fList.push(this);
    }
});
for (i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
    fList[i] = fList[i].split('">')[0];
    fList[i] = fList[i].replace('"');
}

for (i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
    $('#idLoadHere').load(fList[i]);
}
```

Comment: Great! and yes the files are on my server of course. but is it possible to loop them with jQuery?

Comment: I don't think so, you'll need to use ASP.net or PHP. If you are using ASP.net i could show you how to do it

Comment: the url cannot accept folders..so the success function is not called.

Answer (score 0):

- Run FTP list command (there are various ways to do so, Web-Sockets is one..)
- A simpler, more common ans secure-solution is a server-side listing of the files, and "cooking" the HTML *(meaning- embedding the file-listing within it)*,

<sub>*you can use raw HTML or put it in `var` statement to be used by JavaScript (for example).</sub>

see following answer:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/30949072/257319